# Effects of opposite potions and their order of application

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

This only applied to Speed and Slowness potions, Mining Fatigue and Mining Haste. Does applying on then the other (to yourself) change the way the effect you, or change the way the particles show? Also, how does applying them both effect your speed/mining rate. Do they cancel each other out to leave you with the rate you started with, or do they end with a slight buff/debuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Speed and Slowness

The Speed effect increases your player's speed by 20% per level. The Slowness effect decreases your player's speed by 15% per level.

Therefore, if you have the Speed effect with a level of `3*k` and the Slowness effect with a level of `4*k` (where `k` is an integer) your speed will be normal.

## Haste and Mining Fatigue

Haste increases your mining speed by 20% per level. However, Mining Fatigue is bit weird.

For level 1, your mining speed is 30% of its original (70% speed reduction). For level 2, it's 9% of the original, for level 3, it's 0.27%, and for levels 4 and above, it's 0.081%.

So there's no possible combination of of Haste and Mining Fatigue which would "cancel each other out".

## Particles

Both colours of particles are emitted by the player in each of the above cases. Applying one effect does not remove the particles of the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

The rules for the effects seem to be this

First of all, we have to put all the percentages into decimals and set your normal speed (mining and running) as 1.

**Haste and Mining Fatigue**

Mining Fatigue has a rule where it multiplies your mining speed by 0.3 per level, but multiplies it by 0.03 for level three meaning it does this

```
1×0.3×0.3×0.03×0.3
 (I) (II)(III)(IV)
```

and haste has a simple formula of `1+0.2x` where `x` is the level of haste

**Speed and Slowness**

For speed and slowness, it's basically the same as haste where the formula for slowness is `1-0.15x` and the formula for speed is `1+0.2y` where `x` and `y` are the levels of speed and slowness.

In order to counter both the effects, mining fatigue and slowness, you need to multiply a level of speed/haste and the result needs to end up as 1 or more, meaning if I did the math right, mining fatigue 3 and 4+ is impossible to counter completely because the level of haste needed is over 1k.

This is all what I think, which means that I could be wrong and if I am wrong, please correct me if you'd like

Comment: Multiplies by 1.3, I presume (since if you'd multiply by 0.3 it would decrease)?